# Is there a “Move selected file to folder…” command in OSX?

Tags: macos

In finder, I would like to:

1. Select a file
2. Trigger a "Move to folder..." action - e.g. like "Go to folder..." (⇧ + ⌘ + g)

So its basically the same as the bash command:

`mv <Finders selected item> <dest folder>`

Comment: A bit long-winded, but you could use an automator action containing an applescript/shellscript saved as a Service, triggered by a hot key or right-click menu. If no-one finds a simpler solution, it might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind switching Finder windows you can use this method:

1. **Select** the file(s)/folder(s) you want to move.
2. Press <kbd>**CMD+C**</kbd> to copy the selection.
3. Go to your **destination folder** (I often use <kbd>CTRL+TAB</kbd> to cycle through Finder tabs).
4. Press <kbd>**CMD+Option+V**</kbd>. This moves your selection instead of copying it.

Does this work for you?

As pointed out by @Tetsujin, you need to write a service or an AppleScript to do it faster.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can only use a `drag and drop` to move an item in Finder. You simply drag it, then drop it where you want it.

Your other option is to use an alternative to Finder - there are plenty available (Commander One, Moroshka, Files Lite)

Comment: Mac is based loosely on unix, there are many alternatives to drag & drop

Comment: Of course, but we're strictly speaking for `Finder`.

Comment: Think outside the box ;)